# Angular Universal: "Cannot read property '_updateTreeValidity' of undefined"

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to build a dynamic form in Angular Universal. The form is set up so that certain questions are mandatory, and other are not, depending on how the form was designed by it's creator. When displaying the form for the user to fill out, it worked completely fine without Angular Universal (JiT Compiler, vs AoT compiler).

The form includes a custom component that gets injected into each form question allowing the user to enter their response into the component for submission.

The application compiles fine, but when this component is loaded, I get many errors:

> Cannot read property '_updateTreeValidity' of undefined
>
> Cannot read property 'setParent' of undefined
>       at e._registerControl
>
> ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

**This is the typescript for the form:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy, NgZone, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication.service';
import { ProgramsService } from '../../services/programs.service';
import { InfoService } from '../../services/info.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { SessionsService } from '../../services/sessions.service';
import { Answers } from '../formComponents/answers';
import { AnswerComponent } from '../formComponents/answer.component';


@Component({
  templateUrl: './intro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./intro.component.css'],
  providers: [SessionsService, InfoService, ProgramsService]
})
export class IntroComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private _programsService: ProgramsService, private zone: NgZone, private _fb: FormBuilder, private _sessionsService: SessionsService){

    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      questions: this._fb.array([])
    });


    this.subcribeToFormChanges(); 
  }




  programId: string;
  sessionId: string;
  private sub: any;
  res;
  coachUsername;
  welcomeHeader;
  welcomeDescription;
  welcomeFiles;
  requiredQuestions;
  formData: FormData;
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  public events: any[] = [];
  loading;
  introCompleted;
  isForm = false;



  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.sessionId = params['id']; 
      this.getSessionInfo(this.sessionId);
    });
  }





  getSessionInfo(id){
    this.loading = true;
    this._sessionsService.getSession(id).subscribe(res=>{
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(res.programId);
      this.programId = res.programId;
      if(res.introSessionCompleted == false){
        this.introCompleted = false;
        this.getForm();
      }
      if(res.introSessionCompleted == true){
        this.introCompleted = true;
        this.getAnswers();
      }
    })
  }



  getAnswers(){
    this._sessionsService.getAnswerIntro(this.sessionId).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log('session answers');
      console.log(res);
      this.fillAnswers(res);
    })
  }



  fillAnswers(res){
    this.getFormLight();
    for(var i=0; i<res.questions.length; i++){
      this.answerQuestion(res.questions[i].type, res.questions[i].placeholder, res.questions[i].title, res.questions[i].required, res.questions[i].answer);
    }
  }



  getFormLight(){
    this._programsService.clientGetIntro(this.programId).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log('Intro res:')
      console.log(res)
      this.welcomeDescription = res.welcomeDescription;
      this.welcomeHeader = res.welcomeHeader;
      this.welcomeFiles = res.welcomeFiles;
    })
  }

  getForm(){
    this._programsService.clientGetIntro(this.programId).subscribe(res=>{
      this.isForm = true;
      console.log('Intro res:')
      console.log(res)
      this.res = res;
      this.welcomeDescription = res.welcomeDescription;
      this.welcomeHeader = res.welcomeHeader;
      this.welcomeFiles = res.welcomeFiles;
      this.requiredQuestions = res.requiredQuestions;
      if(this.requiredQuestions){
        for(var i=0; i<this.requiredQuestions.length; i++){
          this.addQuestion(this.requiredQuestions[i].type, this.requiredQuestions[i].placeholder, this.requiredQuestions[i].title, this.requiredQuestions[i].required);
        }
      }
    })
  }



  initQuestion(type, placeholder, title, required) {
    if(required == 'yes'){
      return this._fb.group({
      type: [type],
      placeholder: [placeholder],
      title: [title],
      required: [required],
      answer: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    }
    if(required == 'no'){
      return this._fb.group({
      type: [type],
      placeholder: [placeholder],
      title: [title],
      required: [required],
      answer: ['']
    });
    }  

  }

  initAnswerQuestion(type, placeholder, title, required, answer){
    return this._fb.group({
      type: [type],
      placeholder: [placeholder],
      title: [title],
      required: [required],
      answer: new FormControl({value: answer, disabled: true})
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  save(model: Answers, isValid: boolean) {

    this._sessionsService.answerIntro(this.programId, this.sessionId, JSON.stringify(model)).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      if(res.message == 'Finished updating answers'){
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/account/sessions/view/'+this.sessionId)
      }
    })
  }

  addQuestion(type, placeholder, title, required) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['questions'];
    const addrCtrl = this.initQuestion(type, placeholder, title, required);
    control.push(addrCtrl);
  }

  answerQuestion(type, placeholder, title, required, answer) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['questions'];
    const addrCtrl = this.initAnswerQuestion(type, placeholder, title, required, answer);
    control.push(addrCtrl);
  }

  removeQuestion(i: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['questions'];
    control.removeAt(i);
  }

  subcribeToFormChanges() {
    const myFormStatusChanges$ = this.myForm.statusChanges;
    const myFormValueChanges$ = this.myForm.valueChanges;
    myFormStatusChanges$.subscribe(x => this.events.push({ event: 'STATUS_CHANGED', object: x }));
    myFormValueChanges$.subscribe(x => this.events.push({ event: 'VALUE_CHANGED', object: x }));
  }

}
```

**This is the html for the form:**

```
<div class="container animated fadeIn" style="padding-top:140px" >
  <div class="session-container">
  <div class="row nomargin">
    <div class="session-container-header">
      <div *ngIf="introCompleted" class="back" [routerLink]="['/account/sessions/view', sessionId]">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>Session Dashboard
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!introCompleted" class="back" [routerLink]="['/account/sessions']">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>All Sessions
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        Session Introduction
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="introCompleted" class="settings-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-gear" [class.fa-spin]="mouseOvered" (mouseover)="mouseOvered=true" (mouseleave)="mouseOvered=false" [routerLink]="['/account/sessions/view/'+id+'/settings']"></i>
                </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row nomargin">
      <div *ngIf="!loading" class="session-container-content">
        <div class="row nomargin">



        <div class="intro-container">
          <div class="intro-welcome">
            <a>{{welcomeHeader}}</a>
          </div>
          <div class="intro-photo">

          </div>
          <div class="intro-description">
            <a>{{welcomeDescription}}</a>
          </div>


          <div class="intro-files">
            <div class="intro-border">
              <a>Introduction Files</a>
            </div>
            <div class="files-row">
              <div *ngFor="let file of welcomeFiles" class="file-container" [style.background]="'url('+file.url+')'">
                <div class="overlay">
                  <a [href]="file.url" class="file-url"><div class="download-button">
                     <a><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Download</a>
                  </div></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="intro-questions">
            <div class="intro-border">
              <a>Introduction Questions</a>
            </div>
            <form *ngIf="isForm == true;" [formGroup]="myForm"> 
            <div class="intro-answers-container">

              <div *ngFor="let question of myForm.controls.questions.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
                  <answer [group]="myForm.controls.questions[i]"></answer>
              </div>


            </div>           
            </form>

          </div>

          <div *ngIf="!introCompleted && !loading" class="intro-submit">
            <button *ngIf="myForm.valid" class="submit-button" (click)="save(myForm.value, true)">Complete Program Introduction</button>
            <button *ngIf="!myForm.valid" class="submit-button invalid" >Complete Program Introduction</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        </div>


      </div>
      <div *ngIf="loading" class="session-container-content">
        <img class="loading-ring" src="../assets/img/ring.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is the custom answer component typescript**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'answer',
    templateUrl: 'answer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./answer.component.css']
})
export class AnswerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('group')

    public answerForm: FormGroup;


    type;
    title;
    required;
    disabled;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.type = this.answerForm.controls['type'].value;
        this.required = this.answerForm.controls['required'].value;
        this.title = this.answerForm.controls['title'].value;
        if(this.answerForm.controls['answer'].value != null && this.answerForm.controls['answer'].value != ''){
            this.disabled = true;

            console.log('disabled');
        }
    }





}
```

**Lastly, here is the custom component html**

```
    <div [formGroup]="answerForm">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="left-hand">
            <div class="question-text"><a>{{title}}</a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-hand">
            <textarea *ngIf="type=='text'" class="form-answer" placeholder="Type answer here..." formControlName="answer"></textarea>
            <input class="number" type="number" placeholder="Enter answer here..." formControlName="answer" *ngIf="type=='number'" >
            <select *ngIf="type=='yesno'" formControlName="answer" >
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose answer</option>
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
            </select>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, one of the responses for the ngFor objects in the array had blank values, therefore messing up the components.